# TypeScript / Vue 3: Injecting mutating function causes TypeScript error "Object is of type 'unknown'"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, inject, vue-composition-api, mutating-function

I’m new in TypeScript and trying to use it with Vue 3 composition API and provide / inject.
Let's say in parent component `A` I have something like this:

```
// Parent component A

import { provide, ref } from 'vue';
import ScoreType from "@/types/Score";

setup() {
  ..
  const score = ref<ScoreType[]>([]);
  const updateScore = (val: ScoreType) => {
    score.value.push(val);
  };

  provide('update_score', updateScore);  
  ..
}
```

...and then want to inject `updateScore` function in child component `B` to be able to update values in parent component `A` ([this is what docs recommend](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#mutating-reactive-properties)). Unfortunately, I get a TS error `Object is of type 'unknown'`

```
// Child component B

import { inject } from 'vue';

setup() {
  ..
  const updateScore = inject('update_score');
  const checkAnswer = (val: string) => {
    updateScore({ /* ScoreType object */ });  // → Object is of type 'unknown'.
  }
  ..
}
```

What should I do to fix the TypeScript error? I couldn't find any examples about injecting update functions in TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's firstly declare a type for our `updateScore()` function

```
// @/types/score.ts
export type ScoreType = { points: number };

export type UpdateScoreFunction = (val: ScoreType) => void;
```

Now we need to declare an `InjectionKey` which will hold the type information of our provided/injected variable (function in this case). More about it in [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#provide-inject)

Let's make a separate folder to store our keys and to keep the things organized:

```
// @/symbols/score.ts
import { InjectionKey } from "vue";
import { UpdateScoreFunction } from "@/types/score";

export const updateScoreKey: InjectionKey<UpdateScoreFunction> = Symbol("updateScore");
```

In our parent component `(A)`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, provide, ref } from "vue";

import { ScoreType, UpdateScoreFunction } from "@/types/score";
import { updateScoreKey } from "@/symbols/score";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const score = ref<ScoreType[]>([]);
    
    // Actually, adding ': UpdateScoreFunction' is optional 
    const updateScore: UpdateScoreFunction = function (val: ScoreType) {
      score.value.push(val);
    };

    // Replace the string with InjectionKey
    provide(updateScoreKey, updateScore);

    // ...
  },
});
</script>
```

In our child component `(B)`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";
import { updateScoreKey } from "@/symbols/score";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    // Replace the string with InjectionKey
    const updateScore = inject(updateScoreKey);

    // In case the `updateScoreKey` is not provided by the parent component..
    if (updateScore === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Failed to inject "updateScore"');
    }

    const checkAnswer = (val: string) => {

      // ...

      // The error is gone
      updateScore({ 
        points: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      });
    };

    // ...
  },
});
</script>
```

Working example *provided* here: [codesandbox.io/s/so-provide-inject](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-provide-inject-tkhbr?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why do we have to handle possibility of injected function being 'undefined'? I can't imagine scenario when parent (in my app) doesn't have the injected function. Is it related with composition API and composing components from "multiple pieces" maybe?

Comment: It will be `undefined` if you remove `provide(updateScoreKey, updateScore);` from your parent component, because there will be nothing to inject in the child one. If you don't want to handle it, you can pass a second parameter to the `inject()` function in your child component to specify the default value: `const updateScore = inject(updateScoreKey, function() { ... });`.